# how can I convert SWF to JPG?

Tags: images, flash, jpeg, swf

I have some flash files and they are "still" which doesn't contain any animation in it. how can I convert flash files to image without losing quality?

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be to make a screen-shot of your browser while displaying them. Then paste it in your favourite image editor(mine is [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/))
 . This would depend on your OS though.

Answer (score 0):

Since SWF files are vector and bitmap images (+video+scripts) combined, there's no lossless converting to JPG. I assume you downloaded the SWF and it works offline. Otherwise better use screenshots.

Possible solutions:

- use Irfanview for viewing (doesn't need flash, but might throw errors)
- try converting to HTML5 or extract the images using online tools(might throw errors)